# Mod inbox is acting strangely

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, global-inbox, top-bar

My Chemistry mod inbox looks like this:

[image]

No meta questions are shown, despite there having been [a meta question on Dec 15](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/should-the-tag-covalent-bond-be-split).

I have the opposite effect on Physics:

[image]

There was [a mod message reply](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/message/268#268) after Nov 26, but it is not there in the inbox. I don't recall seeing it there at any point, though I also use the genuwine inbox (Since the chat topbar is not yet updated and I also use StackAlert)

In addition, the meta questions seem to disappear from the inbox on Phy rather rapidly.

Comment: did you break it?